# What can be said about the properties of a DFT matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let us say that we are given a DFT matrix $\Omega_n$ with $2$ signals $z, w \in \mathbb{C^n}$, such that $\hat{z}=\Omega_n z, \hat{w}=\Omega_n w$ are the discrete Fourier Transformation from $z$ and $w$. If the columns of $\Omega_n$ are normalised, then can we say that $\widehat{z_{n-1}}$ describes the share of the highest frequencies of $z$?

Can we then use this to say that, the convolution of $a$ and $a$ corresponds to the elemental multiplication of the transformed signals: $z ∗ w = \hat{z}⋅\hat{w}$?

Comment: Presumably, you mean $\widehat{z * w} = \hat z \cdot \hat w$

Comment: Note that for vectors or matrices, the element-wise product is often called the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. I meant $z ∗ w = \hat{z}⋅\hat{w}$.

Comment: Still, it should be $\widehat{z * w}$, not $z*w$.

Comment: Hmmm ... but on the exercise sheet it's written to either prove or disprove that $z ∗ w = \hat{z}⋅\hat{w}$. So by using what you said, I would have to disprove $z ∗ w = \hat{z}⋅\hat{w}$.

Comment: Does $*$ refer to a [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution)?

Comment: Yes it does refer to that.

Comment: Given what's on the exercise sheet, either there is a typo or you are meant to disprove the statement.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the $\widehat{z_{n-1}}$?

Comment: It's not clear how I should interpret the phrase "$\hat z_{n-1}$ describes the share of the highest frequencies", so it's hard to say whether it is correct.

Comment: Because of aliasing, calling anything a "high frequency component" is a bit tricky.  But if we think of $e^{\frac{2 \pi i (N-1)}{N}n }$ as being the signal of highest frequency, then yes your interpretation of $\hat z_{n-1}$ makes sense. Keep in mind, however, that we could have written the same signal as $e^{\frac{-2 \pi i }{N}n }$, which we would normally think of as having a low frequency.

Comment: AH I was missing that link. Thanks! If you would like, you can move this to an answer and I can accept it so others can also see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the convolution property of the DFT means that $\widehat{z*w} = \hat z \cdot \hat w$.  The statement $z*w = \hat z \cdot \hat w$ does not hold in general.

Regarding $\hat z_{n-1}$: because of aliasing, calling anything a "high frequency component" is a bit tricky.  But if we think of $e^{\frac{2 \pi i (N-1)}{N}n }$ as being the signal of highest frequency, then yes your interpretation of $\hat z_{n-1}$ makes sense. Keep in mind, however, that we could have written the same signal as $e^{\frac{-2 \pi i }{N}n }$, which we would normally think of as having a low frequency.